# Using global variable vs local variable and require

Tags: c++, lua

I've been told that using global variable is bad and using `require` to get local variable is a better design.

I ran a simple test to figure out if there's any difference in performance between the two approaches.

My Code:

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

void main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    //Script A
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function () local A = {}\n"
                     "function A:mult(a,b) return a * b end\n"
                     "return A end");

    std::clock_t startcputime1 = std::clock();

    //Script B
    for (int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
        luaL_dostring(L, "local A = require 'A' A:mult(2,3)");

    double cpu_duration1 = (std::clock() - startcputime1) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Finished in " << cpu_duration1 << " seconds [CPU Clock] " << std::endl;
    lua_close(L);


    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    //Script A
    luaL_dostring(L, "A = {} function A:mult(a,b) return a * b end\n");

    std::clock_t startcputime2 = std::clock();

    //Script B
    for (int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
        luaL_dostring(L, "A:mult(2,3)");

    double cpu_duration2 = (std::clock() - startcputime2) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Finished in " << cpu_duration2 << " seconds [CPU Clock] " << std::endl;
    lua_close(L);
}
```

Result:

```
Finished in 0.739236 seconds [CPU Clock] 
Finished in 0.479537 seconds [CPU Clock]
```

As you can see, using the global variable `A` is faster than using the local variable `A` and `require`.

Could this mean it is better to use the global variable to share data if performance is the important factor in my app?

Comment: Performance of what? I don't trust those measurements (the difference seems way too big), and even if, this is the loading time of the program. This is a very unlikely place to provide good optimization possibilities. To judge whether one is preferrable over the other, we'd need way more specifics. All things aside, I don't think that exposing data to embedded Lua as readily accesible globals is *that* bad, but it depends on the *actual use case*. But that should probably be done directly through the `loaded` table, just as Nicol Bolas pointed in comments on your other question.

Comment: CPU time is also a bad measure.  Multi-threaded programs usually need a lot more CPU time than single-threaded programs, yet they are faster and need less wall time (the time on your watch or wall clock).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I agree that communicating with the embedded interpreter via globals is reasonable but OP want to have different Lua chunks running in the embedded interpreter communicate via globals which I advised against because it leads to a lot of confusion since the order in which chunks are run matters.

Comment: Do you really think that accessing variables will be the bottleneck in your app? Shouldn't the Lua code actually do something and this something will be so much faster that the difference between local vs global will no longer matter? Also, if performance is so critical, why do you use Lua at all? In a compiled language, things *could* be faster. My point here is that you are making a trade-off.

Comment: "*As you can see, using the global variable A is faster than using the local variable A and require.*" No, what I see here is that it takes longer to parse and compile a longer string than a shorter one. A *proper* performance test would not include the parsing and compilation of the string; only its *execution* time. So you need to use `loadstring` outside of the timed portion, and then execute the function repeatedly.

Comment: The test is not necessarily measuring the time required to access variables. The global variable test just accesses a global variable and calls a method once per loop body, but the local variable test creates a new local variable and calls `require` along with what the global variable test does. So the local variable test adds the overhead of defining a new variable and calling a function. It would be fairer if both tests defined a variable outside the loop (global or local depending on the test) and simply accessed it and called the method inside the loop.

Comment: If you do the benchmark properly ([source](https://hastebin.com/otetecubuf.cpp)) by disregarding the cost of parsing, the two take the [same time](https://hastebin.com/azihiyevor.shell) within one standard deviation.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you so much for showing me how to benchmark correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could this mean it is better to use the global variable to share data if performance is the important factor in my app?

I'm going to ignore the issues with your benchmark that I pointed out in a comment. I'll assume that you performed an accurate benchmark and determined that global variables are faster.

In order for this to be worth doing, you would need to do more than just prove that performance is important to your app. You would have to prove that the *specific* performance caused by the access of module-local variables is important to your app. Most applications do not spend the majority of their time accessing local variables. Their performance issues typically come from algorithms, from processes they're performing, waiting on hard disk access, or things of that nature.

The purpose of the advice you were given was to ensure *correctness* in your application. By keeping module-local variables in their own table, you make it impossible for one module to damage another. So disregarding that advice on the basis of an artificial test without knowing that it will measurably improve your actual application's performance is not wise.

Or, as it has been said, premature optimization is the root of all evil.